# Watin: How to hide FileDownloadHandler window?

Tags: c#, .net, watin

I'm using watin to auto download a file from the internet however, i can hide the ie window but not the FileDownloadHandler window

I use the following to hide ie:

```
 ie.ShowWindow(WatiN.Core.Native.Windows.NativeMethods.WindowShowStyle.Hide);
```

Here how i create the Download window:

```
var fileDownloadHandler = new FileDownloadHandler(file.FullName);
ie.AddDialogHandler(fileDownloadHandler);
```

How can i hide the download dialog box?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by `hide` ? Do you mean you want to close the file dialog after you finish the download?

Comment: No i mean, run it in the background without been displayed!

Comment: Surprised that no one has faced this problem before.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem with another function ,you just set Url,save path and all works and you dont see any popUp.
add this in class

```
[DllImport("urlmon.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
static extern Int32 URLDownloadToFile(Int32 pCaller, string szURL, string szFileName, Int32 dwReserved, Int32 lpfnCB);
```

and this function

```
 int lwhdr = URLDownloadToFile(0, Link, FilePath, 0, 0);
```